expo react-native-google-mobile-ads android crashing on app load
I recently migrated to Expo 50, and since then any APK I build is crashing on load, with the error:
Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Invalid application ID
It currently works fine for iOS.
I've tried so many different way to configure the id (again this was working for years before this migration.
I'm using "expo": "~50.0.20" and "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^14.2.5"
What I've tried, in various different combinations, and by themselves:
AndroidManifest.xml
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
  android:value="ca-app-pub-7389480061982385~6737417759"
  tools:replace="android:value"
/>

app.config.js
module.exports = {
  expo: {
    name: APP-NAME,
    slug: MY-SLUG,
    scheme: MY-SCHEMA,
    version: "2.0.3",
    orientation: "portrait",
    icon: "./assets/icon.png",
    userInterfaceStyle: "light",
    splash: {
      image: "./assets/splash.png",
      resizeMode: "contain",
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    },

    platforms: ["ios", "android", "web"],
    updates: {
      fallbackToCacheTimeout: 0,
    },
    assetBundlePatterns: ["**/*"],
    ios: {
      supportsTablet: true,
      bundleIdentifier: MY-BUNDLE-IDENTIFIER,
      buildNumber: "1.0.0",
    },
    android: {
      package: MY-PACKAGE,
      googleServicesFile:
        process.env.GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON ?? "/android/app/google-services.json",
      versionCode: 58,
      permissions: [],
      playStoreUrl:
        "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=MY-APP",
      adaptiveIcon: {
        foregroundImage: "./assets/icon.png",
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
      },
      config: {
         googleMobileAdsAppId: "ca-app-pub-MY~KEY",
      },
    },
    web: {
      favicon: "./assets/favicon.png",
    },
    extra: {
      "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
        android_app_id: "ca-app-pub-MY~KEY",
        ios_app_id: "ca-app-pub-MY~KEY",
      },
      eas: {
        projectId: MY-PROJECT-ID,
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      [
        "react-native-google-mobile-ads",
        {
          android_app_id: "ca-app-pub-MY~KEY",
          ios_app_id: "ca-app-pub-MY~KEY",
        },
      ],
    ],
  },
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    android_app_id: "ca-app-pub-MY~KEY",
    ios_app_id: "ca-app-pub-MY~KEY",
  },
};


I've been struggling a bit with the migration from expo 49 to 52, and admob 13 to 14.
The breaking change seems to suggest that android_app_id should now be passed in as androidAppId to the plugin, so it might be as simple as making that change in your case.
You seem to be providing the android app id in 3 places in your app.json file, so you might want to make sure you update the key in all 3 places, and any other references that you might have in your source code.
